# Focus/Scroll recyclerView to last Item

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

My app has main, chat style, activity made of a RecycleView which is filled by a list. the recycle should scroll/focus to the last item of the list after the user insert a new item (text input, photo/video capture) but recycler keeps focus on the first item inside the list even after using recyclerView.scrollToPosition(CustomList.size()-1).

complete code available at: https://github.com/MikeSys/ChatApp

---

### MainActivity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);

    // Elementi Grafici-----------------------------------------

    RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    Button video = findViewById(R.id.video);
    Button camera = findViewById(R.id.camera);
    Button send = findViewById(R.id.send);
    videoView =findViewById(R.id.rec);
    final EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);

    // Media Controller----------------------------------------



    // Layout Manager------------------------------------------------

    linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this);
    linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);


    // Adapter-----------------------------------------

    if(dati.size()> 1){  
        adapter =  new myAdapter(dati, this);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        adapter.notifyItemInserted(dati.size()-1);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        //Setted recyclerView to scroll to the last item of the List
        recyclerView.scrollToPosition(dati.size()-1);
    }


    else{
        adapter =  new myAdapter(dati,this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

---

### MainActivity Layout

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:background="@drawable/sfondo"
    android:foregroundGravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/editText"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
    app:stackFromEnd="true"/>


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="160dp"
    android:background="#0003A9F4"
    android:hint="Scrivi"
    android:padding="20dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="3"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/send"
    android:layout_width="55dp"
    android:layout_height="64dp"
    android:background="@drawable/send"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/editText"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/editText"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/editText"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/camera"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:background="@drawable/camera"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/editText"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/send"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/editText"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/editText"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/video"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/video"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/camera"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/editText"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/recyclerView" />
```

---

### Screenshots

[image]

Comment: did you tried using `LinearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true)`

Comment: try commenting the code where you are scrolling to position, just keep the setreverselayout.

Comment: you are setting `linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);` and not `setReverseLayout` both of them are different.

Comment: the problem is that I need settackFromEnd otherwise items get generated from the top of the recycler

Answer (score 1):

use

> recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(position);

**position** is your index of last item inserted. This will move your the RecyclerView focus on the last element.

Comment: Can you please take a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64332032/how-to-focus-scroll-to-a-specific-item-in-recyclerview-by-fetching-item-position