# How to focus/scroll to a specific item in recyclerView by fetching item position

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have to scroll to a specific item in a recyclerview.

Firstly I need to fetch the position of the item by matching with a string which I pass from the activity to the adapter. then to focus to that item position.

For example in the adapter there is a TextView which has *EventID* stored, I will pass a string from activity to adapter to match it with the *EventID* and then fetch that item position and set focus/scroll to that particular position. I have defined a method in adapter to fetch position of item but I don't know how to call it from the activity since it has *viewholder* as parameter.

I'm confused about how to implement `recyclerView.scrollToPosition(mSkipTo)` or something else to achieve this. How to call it in my activity.  Kindly give a code example since I'm new to this.

```
public class EventsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<EventsAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private Context context;
private final List<EventsDataModel> eventsDataModels;
private static int currentPosition = 0;


public EventsAdapter(Context context) {

    super();
    this.context = context;
    this.eventsDataModels = new ArrayList<EventsDataModel>();

}

public void updateModels(List<EventsDataModel> newModels) {
    eventsDataModels.clear();
    eventsDataModels.addAll(newModels);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.event_card_new, parent, false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
    final EventsDataModel dataAdapter = eventsDataModels.get(position);
    ......
    ......
    viewHolder.EventID.setText(dataAdapter.getEventID());



    viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if (context instanceof EventsActivity) {
                ((EventsActivity) context).clickOnEventType(viewHolder.EventID.getText().toString());
            }

        }
    });
}

//How to call this method from activity ? Since ViewHolder cannot be obtained from there

public int getItemPosition(ViewHolder viewHolder,String inEventID){
    int itemPos=0;
    if (viewHolder.EventID.getText().equals(inEventID)) {
        itemPos  =  viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
    }
    return itemPos;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return eventsDataModels.size();
}


}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33329765/10182897

Comment: Could you please tell me how to do this in my code. How should I fetch the position from adapter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add public function into your adapter.

```
public class EventsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<EventsAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    ...
public int getItemPosition(String eventId) {
    for (int i = 0; i < eventsDataModels.size(); i++) {
        if (eventsDataModels.get(i).getEventID().equals(eventId)) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Activity:

```
private void scrollToPosition() {
    String eventId = "someId";
    int position = adapter.getItemPosition(eventId);
    if (position >= 0) {
        recycler.scrollToPosition(position);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please have a look at another question of mine? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64459556/app-crashes-while-calling-locationupdatesservice-with-permission-with-nullpointe

Answer (score 1):

Expose an interface and implement it in your activity. In that interface declare a method that returns an Integer value (Position).Call that method in your onClick.
Set the interface from the activity and override the method and use `recyclerView.scrollToPosition(mSkipTo)`.

Comment: I want to pass a string from activity to adapter, then matches it and get its position and then focus to that specific item.  It would be more helpful if you could explain in the code since I'm new to this. Thanks